# How to resize a DOS window to size greater than 320?

Tags: windows-7, dosbox

How to resize a DOS window to size greater than 320?  Is it possible?

I wanted to have one of my Dos windows the width of my screen, but I can't make it larger than 320.  If I chose a value larger than 320, then Window Size Width changes to 320 and the Screen Buffer Size width is set to the actual value that I entered for the Window size. That gives me the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom, which is not what I'm after.

[image]

Comment: So is you goal to have more than 320 columns, or to fill your screen with command-prompt?

Comment: More than 320, although I am approaching screen width...but not quite.  I would like to use more of my screen width-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Windows PowerShell or use an alternative Shell like http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: I am using Console now--same issue.

Comment: Just tested with PowerShell--can't go  wider than 240

Comment: Sorry those suggestions didn't help, I could not test these solutions here. I was pretty sure, that you could freely resize the Console2 window to any size you want.

Comment: PowerCmd works though.